# How to sort only number values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

var points = [2, a, t, 5, 4, 3];
and after sort:
var points = [2, a, t, 3, 4, 5];

Any help about that? it is possible to post your help with old style javascript code because i work on Adobe DC project?

my code is there :

```
var points = [t1, t2, t3, t4];
[t1, t2, t3, t4] = points;

var lucky = points.filter(function(number) {
  return isNaN(number) == false && number !=="" && number!== undefined;
});
points=lucky
points.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});

this.getField("Text6").value = points
```

but this only sort min to max and filter other characters... i need to keep other characters and short only numbers...

Comment: Welcome to SO. The idea is you show what you've tried, then we help.

Comment: without showing code, I could suggest to splice the array sort it separately and then combine it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var points = [2, "a", "t", 5, 4, 11, "", 3];
var insert = points.slice(0); // Clone points

// Remove all elements not a number
points = points.filter(function(element) {
  return typeof element === 'number';
});

// Sort the array with only numbers
points.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});

// Re-insert all non-number elements
insert.forEach(function(element, index) {
  if (typeof element !== 'number') {
    points.splice(index, 0, element);
  }
});

console.log(points);
```

Comment: Nice. Actually this looks like a good interview question to use in the future given how many answerers (myself included) got this wrong

Comment: I agree @pete, it's deceptively simple.

Comment: Why used only `sort()` it will not work for greater numbers.

Comment: @Armel one bug i found is to short and "" values... and not keep is the table position how to fix this?

Comment: @MaheerAli You are right, I have added a compare function in the `sort()`.

Comment: @hackertom I fixed the problem with empty strings `""`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this more efficiently by avoiding `splice()` if you simply reassign the values in place.

Filter, sort, the reassign to sort the numbers in place:

```js
let arr = ['c', 2, 'a', 't', 5, 4, 3, 'b', 1]

let n = arr.filter(c => typeof c == "number").sort((a, b) => a-b)
for (let i = 0, c=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (typeof arr[i] == "number") arr[i] = n[c++]
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I like your condensed solution but I kept something a bit more verbose and less ES6. I guess it depends on what you are looking for ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` numbers out of array. Then `sort()` them and then loop through real array. And check if value is `Number` change it will first element of sorted array. And remove first element of `sortedArr`

```js
let arr = [5, 't', 's', 2,3,4];
let sortedNums = arr.filter(x => typeof x === 'number').sort((a,b) => a-b);
arr.forEach((a,i) => {
  if(typeof a === 'number'){
    arr[i] = sortedNums[0]
    sortedNums.shift();
  } 
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer ‍♂️ True

Answer (score 0):

The following should give the exact output given your input:

```js
var result = [2, 'a', 't', 5, 4, 3].reduce(
  function(result,item){
    return !isNaN(item)&&item!==''
      ? typeof (result[result.length-1] && result[result.length-1].push) === 'function'
        ? (result[result.length-1].push(item),result)
        : result.concat([[item]])
      : result.concat(item)
  },
  []
).map(
  function(item){
    return typeof item.sort === 'function'
      ? item.sort(function(a,b){return a-b})
      : item
  }
).reduce(
  function(result,item){
    return result.concat(item)
  },[]
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The way I read the question was to sort all the numbers as a single group rather than sorting the subgroups of numbers. For example, the expected output of `[2, 'a', 't', 5, 4, 3, 1]` would be `[1, 'a', 't', 2, 3, 4, 5]`. The code above returns `[ 2, 'a', 't', 1, 3, 4, 5 ]`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer could be the case as well